# segue move from CollectionView didSelect Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

in my code

```
....
class MenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
..
..///some code here
..
}

extension MenuTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuItems.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "menuItemCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuItemViewCell
    cell.menuItemName = menuItems[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let iconImage  = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    print("iconImage === ",iconImage,section)
    print("Collection view at row \(section) selected index path \(indexPath.row)")

    if (section == 0){
        if(indexPath.row==0) {
            print("inside 0 0")
                 performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: nil)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

but it shows an error that

Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue'

How can i do this...

Comment: Only a UIViewController can do `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`. A `UITableViewCell` can't. So use a closure/delegate to tell the `UIViewController` showing the Cell to perform the segue.

Answer (score 1):

Well a table view cell does not have a method to `performSegue`. You will need to either forward your message to some view controller or make the view controller a data source for the collection view.

Since you might have multiple cells with collection views I suggest you to use the first solution (forward the message to view controller).

So simply create a delegate:

```
protocol MenuTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func menuTableViewCellShouldNavigateHome(_ sender: MenuTableViewCell)
}
```

add a property in your cell to it. Ensure it is weak:

```
class MenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
..
    weak var delegate: MenuTableViewCellDelegate?
```

and call to it in collection view delegate:

```
if(indexPath.row==0) {
    print("inside 0 0")
    delegate?.menuTableViewCellShouldNavigateHome(self)
}
```

Now in your table view data source (which I hope is a view controller) find a method cell for row at index path where you create your cell and set self as a delegate

```
cell.delegate = self
return cell
```

and implement a protocol

```
extension MyViewController: MenuTableViewCellDelegate {
    func menuTableViewCellShouldNavigateHome(_ sender: MenuTableViewCell) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: nil)
    }
}
```